# R Quantile Error - replacement has n rows, data has p

Tags: r, quantile

I am trying to create classify a certain variable (referred to as wt_avg in code) according to top 30 percentile, middle 40 percentile, and bottom 30 percentile.

For example -

```
structure(list(x = 1:10, class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 
3)), .Names = c("x", "class"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

where "x" is the data and "class" is the output I want.

This is the code I am using -

```
sent_data$wt_avg = with(sent_data, SENT_Orth_1 + SENT_Orth_2 + SENT_Orth_3)
sent_data$state = quantile(sent_data$wt_avg, probs = c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1) 
           na.rm = TRUE)
```

I get the following error -

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "state", value = c(-13.38, -2.9725,  : replacement has 5 rows, data has 603

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The output of `quantile` is slightly different.  It returns an output with length different than the initial vector i.e. `quantile(1:10, c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1))#
  0%  30%  70% 100% 
 1.0  3.7  7.3 10.0`  You could store it as a summarised dataset instead of a new column

Comment: Ah okay! I then have to use 'if' conditions to actually create the "state" variable to classify? Is there a faster method? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about not adding a reproducible example and expected output. I have edited my question now.

Comment: I posted a solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `quantile` within `cut` or `findInterval`

```
sent_data$newclass <- with(sent_data, findInterval(x, quantile(x,
         probs = c(0, 0.3, 0.7, 1)), rightmost.closed = TRUE))
sent_data
#    x class newclass
#1   1     1        1
#2   2     1        1
#3   3     1        1
#4   4     2        2
#5   5     2        2
#6   6     2        2
#7   7     2        2
#8   8     3        3
#9   9     3        3
#10 10     3        3
```